# How to link to other code implementation?

Tags: c++

How to link duplicate implementation with different name? method getWindowTitle and getText have same implementation.

```
class Window 
{
  public:
    Window();
    void getWindowTitle()
    {
      cout << "Text";
    }
};

class Button
{
  public:
    Button();
    // i want implementation of get title inside getText
    void getText()
};
```

Comment: Why is copying the code not an option? Is inheriting one from one class to the other and then calling an option? Is putting the shared codein to a non-class function and calling that from both an option? In short, what is your problem with doing what you want?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear but if you would like to avoid copying the code, you may have many solutions. However each solutions may have drawbacks (typically, impacting the `Button` class when you modify the `Window` class, which may not be what you want)

For instance:

- declare the `getWindowTitle()` as static and simply reuse it within the `Button`class

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Window
{
  public:
    Window();
    static void getWindowTitle()
    {
      std::cout << "Text";
    }
};

class Button
{
  public:
    Button(){}
    // i want implementation of get title inside getText
    void getText()
    {
        Window::getWindowTitle();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Button a;
    a.getText();
}
```

- you may inherit `Button` from the class `Window`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Window
{
  public:
    Window(){}
    void getWindowTitle()
    {
      std::cout << "Text";
    }
};

class Button: public Window
{
  public:
    Button(){}
    // i want implementation of get title inside getText
    void getText()
    {
        this->getWindowTitle();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Button a;
    a.getText();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

usually widgets libraries got a base class 'widget' or 'window' that collects all the widget's common implementation and all other more complex class are derived from it.
let's do an example:

```
class Widget
{
public:
    void SetPosition(int x, int y);
    void SetSize(int w, int h);
    void SetName(const std::string& name);
    
    void GetPosition(int* x, int* y);
    void GetSize(int* w, int* h);
    std::string GetName();
    std::string GetTitle();
};


class Button : public Widget
{
public:
    //Button class inherited all public and protected members of Widget
    std::string GetText(){
        return GetTitle();
    }
}
```